# How to save a large array of 5 bit numbers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

How to efficiently save and access a large array of 5 bit numbers in memory?

For example
01100
01101
01110
01111
10000
10001

which I will later convert to a byte to check what number it is?

I was thinking of just using an array of bytes but after a while this will be wasting a lot of memory as this will be a continually growing array. Also I will want to save this array efficiently. I will only be using exactly 5 bits.

Comment: How large is "large"?  More than a million elements?  More than 100 million?

Comment: if you want to go crazy you can stick three at a time in a 'short'. this way you have 1 extra for each 3.

Comment: Is the order of elements important?

Comment: If you don't know ho big this array will be then you should use a list, otherwise you could run out of memory.
By the way I don't understand your question, if each number is 5 bit you could use either a 'byte' array or a 'int' array, it won't make much difference, with an int array you could waste at worst 31 bit, with the byte array only 3 bit.

Comment: @MeikVtune Yes, the order is extremely important.

Comment: @markspace 640, 5 bit values per second ever growing. Although eventually I will have to serialize and save this after using 32gb of memory.

Comment: @AR89 I would like to waste no bits since this will be an ever growing thing and I want to be as efficient as possible. Each 5 bit value will be a set of instructions for a deterministic simulation. At the same time I don't want to do string magic that would potentially cause an unnecessary slow down of reading all these values in a loop.

Comment: Then I'd use a List where you write the data each minute. Since the List provides a `remove` and `add`, you can always add the new bits within a byte(I'd set the first 3 bit to 0, but that's up to you) and each minute(interval of your choice) write 640 * 60 entries to wherever you want.

Comment: That's 400 bytes per second, which is not much.  It works out to 55.3 Mbytes per day though without compression.  You'll have to create some form of permanent storage. I'd suggest start with one log file per day, keep it simple.  See if that meets your requirements or if you are forced to do more.

Comment: A List would be the safest structure then, if you use a list of 'byte' you will waste 3 bit totally.
Look for a 'bit array', instead of an array it would be a list but you can use the same algorithm.

Comment: @AR89 Wouldn't I be wasting 3 bits for every value though? Which will add up over time.

Comment: @ImbarM. better yet why not store it as a long and save even more waste! You should post an answer on an easy way to do this!

Comment: No, because if you use a 'bit array' you will waste only the last bits. Search for it, it's a very common structure. With a bit array you use only the bits that you need because you insert them using bit operations.

Comment: @AR89 or post it here showing how to put in and take out the 5 bit numbers for processing so I can choose you as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I use for a bit array implementation in C, in JAVA it's going to be the same, I must reconsider what I said about the list, maybe an array is going to be better.

Anyway, you consider the array as a contiguous segments of bits. Those functions set, get, and read the k-th bit of the array. In this case I'm using an array of integers, so you see '32', is you use an array of bytes, then you'd use '8'.

```
void set_bit(int a[], int k)
{
    int i = k / 32;
    int pos = k % 32;
    unsigned int flag = 1;  // flag = 0000....00001
    flag = flag << pos;     // flag = 0000...00100..0000
    a[i] = a[i] | flag;     // set the bit at the k-th position in a[i]
}

void clear_bit(int a[], int k)
{
    int i = k / 32;
    int pos = k % 32;
    unsigned int flag = 1;  // flag = 0000....00001
    flag = flag << pos;     // flag = 0000...00100..0000
    flag = ~flag;

    a[i] = a[i] & flag;     // set the bit at the k-th position in a[i]
}

int test_bit(int a[], int k)
{
    int i = k / 32;
    int pos = k % 32;
    unsigned int flag = 1;  // flag = 0000....00001
    flag = flag << pos;     // flag = 0000...00100..0000

    if (a[i] & flag)        // test the k-th bit of a to be 1
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I don't know how you store the five bits number, you'll have to insert them bit by bit, and also keep track of the last empty position in the bit array.

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around making this 5 bit values.

Comment: What's the input you're getting? Int numbers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> "I was thinking of just using an array of bytes but after a while this will   be wasting a lot of memory as this will be a continually growing array."

I've dealt with a similar problem and decided to write a file based [BitInputStream](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/10au/homework/ass8/BitInputStream.java) and a [BitOutputSteam](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/10au/homework/ass8/BitOutputStream.java). Therefore running out of memory was no longer an issue. Please note that the given links are not my work but good examples of how to write a bit input/output stream.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an implementation of a 5-bit byte vector on top of an 8-bit byte vector in Javascript some time ago that might be of some help.

```js
const ByteVector = require('bytevector');

class FiveBuffer {
    constructor(buffer = [0], bitsAvailable = 8) {
        this.buf = new ByteVector(buffer);
        this.bitsAvailable = bitsAvailable;
        this.size = Math.floor(((this.byteSize() * 8) - this.bitsAvailable) / 5);
    }
    push(num) {
        if (num > 31 || num < 0)
            throw new Error(`Only 5-bit unsigned integers (${num} not among them) are accepted`);
        var firstShift = 5 - this.bitsAvailable;
        var secondShift = this.bitsAvailable + 3;
        var firstShifted = shiftRight(num, firstShift);
        var backIdx = this.buf.length - 1;
        var back = this.buf.get(backIdx);
        this.buf.set(backIdx, back | firstShifted);
        if (secondShift < 8) {
            var secondShifted = num << secondShift;
            this.buf.push(secondShifted);
        }
        this.bitsAvailable = secondShift % 8;
        this.size++;
    }
    get(idx) {
        if (idx > this.size)
            throw new Error(`Index ${idx} is out of bounds for FiveBuffer of size ${this.size}`);
        var bitIdx = idx * 5;
        var byteIdx = Math.floor(bitIdx / 8);
        var byte = this.buf.get(byteIdx);
        var bit = bitIdx % 8;

        var firstShift = 3 - bit;
        var firstShifted = shiftRightDestroy(byte, firstShift);
        var final = firstShifted;
        var secondShift = 11 - bit;
        if (secondShift < 8) {
            var secondShifted = this.buf.get(byteIdx + 1) >> secondShift;
            final = final | secondShifted;
        }
        return final;
    }
    buffer() {
        this.buf.shrink_to_fit();
        return this.buf.buffer();
    }
    debug() {
        var arr = [];
        this.buffer().forEach(x => arr.push(x.toString(2)));
        console.log(arr);
    }
    byteSize() {
        return this.buf.size();
    }
}

function shiftRightDestroy(num, bits) {
    var left = 3 - bits;
    var res = (left > 0) ? ((num << left) % 256) >> left : num;
    return shiftRight(res, bits);
}

function shiftRight(num, bits) {
    return (bits < 0) ?
        num << -bits :
        num >> bits;
}

module.exports = FiveBuffer;
```